# Dynamically updated menubar divided in categories

Tags: html, angularjs, navigation, angularjs-ng-repeat

On my website, I want to make a navigation bar just like [this](https://skyblueguy.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/archive_tree.jpg), with categories (here 2012) and articles (here May - October). I've got a JSON object with all categories (id, name) and one with all articles (id, title, body, category), which angular gets for me.

The current HTML is as follows:

```
<!-- The angular controllers are already initialized before this piece of code -->
<div class="menubar">
  <ul>
    <li class="cat" ng-repeat="infocategory in info.infocategories">
      {{infocategory.name}}
      <ul>
        <li class="arti" ng-repeat="infoentry in info.infoentries">
          <!-- The link links to a function that sets the correct tab -->
          <a href ng-click="tab.setTab({{infoentry.id}})">{{infoentry.title}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
app.controller('InfoController', ['$http', function($http){
    var info = this;
    info.infocategories = [];
    info.infoentries = [];

    // This all works correctly
    $http.get(api + 'info_categories?pageSize=20&pageNumber=1').success(function(data){
        info.infocategories = data.data;
    });

    $http.get(api + 'info_posts?pageSize=20&pageNumber=1').success(function(data){
        info.infoentries = data.data;
    });
}]);
```

However, as you can imagine, this code displays *all* entries under the categories, but I want only the entries that belong to the specific category to be displayed.

I'm relatively new to AngularJS, so any help is greatly appreciated. If there's any code lacking or unclear, please tell me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I already fixed it myself. I guess I was thinking too difficult...

```
<div class="menubar">
    <ul>
        <li class="cat" ng-repeat="infocategory in info.infocategories">
            {{infocategory.name}}
            <ul>
                <li class="arti" ng-repeat="infoentry in info.infoentries" ng-show="infoentry.cat == infocategory.id">
                    <a href ng-click="tab.setTab(infoentry.id)">{{infoentry.title}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```